# java.io.IOException: Owner failed to convert data

Tags: java, clipboard

When copying an image from the clipboard into my application, I get :

```
java.io.IOException: Owner failed to convert data
    at sun.awt.X11.XSelection.validateDataGetter(XSelection.java:444)
    at sun.awt.X11.XSelection.getData(XSelection.java:305)
    at sun.awt.X11.XClipboard.getClipboardData(XClipboard.java:120)
    at sun.awt.datatransfer.SunClipboard.getData(SunClipboard.java:225)
```

According to [this](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7107490), it appears that the issues is from jdk 1.7.0. Great. But what can I do for my users that are currently using Java 7 (except asking them to migrate to java 8 ?)

Or maybe I didn't understand the issue ?

Comment: You can discuss/buy premier or extended support from Oracle, and see if that includes fixing this bug. Jdk7 has been end-of-public-updates for more than 2 years. It's probably a better idea to migrate to jdk8. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/eol-135779.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer is probably useless, but I post.
According to Bugzilla tickets [JDK-7107490](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7107490) and [JDK-7199196](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7199196), these bugs are fixed from jdk8. So, it's better recommending to migrate to java 8.

I'm not so familiar with JDK's updating schedule, but I think JDK7 is no more maintained (EOL: [Java 7 Reaches End of Life](https://www.infoq.com/news/2015/05/Oracle-Ends-Java-7Public-Updates)). If you created any patches for this bug, it would not be merged.